# What is involved in moving the gas line in my basement up a few inches?

Tags: pipe, gas

I have gas lines that stick out about 1 inch below the joists in my basement.  This actually starts right where the pipes enter my basement - they go over and then down.  I need that "down" part to be a few inches shorter.

So my choice is to fur out a 3 foot section in the ceiling (which will look fine because it is against the back wall) or to get the pipe moved up.  The section that needs rerouting is 20 feet.

So my question is really about who I would hire to do this, and what would be involved in doing it?

Comment: Just got a quote for $250... ouch

Comment: Well - Plumbers and Gas Fitters work on a quite high equivalent hourly rate. The quote you got does not seem all that out of line if you consider that the person could spend five hours at your site taking down the old pipe, adapting the pipe to the new installation and then pressure testing the resultant install. Pressure testing itself is labor and time consuming because all gas using devices on the line need to be disconnected and capped for the pressure test.

Comment: Costs vary from region to region and since the question seems like it is mostly about costs, I think it is off-topic because its too localized

Comment: Why is this closed?  I wanted to know the process of what they were going to do to reroute it.  I am trying to figure out what I am paying for.  My black iron is all segmented so they are basically adding a couple elbows on each side and connecting.  That is two elbows on each side.  Don't get me on the dangers of gas... maybe if you aren't home.

Comment: @dmoore Questions about cost are off-topic -- see the [faq#note-the-following-are-considered-off-topic].  I voted to re-open because the core question about what tasks are involved is OK because (a) it can help you decide between DIY or hiring a gas contractor, and (b) if you get a quote from a contractor, you'll have a better idea if they're charging you for something you don't need.

Comment: It's not doing the work that costs the money, it's know which work to do.

Comment: Yea I just want to know what they are going to do.  I mentioned cost only because I am referencing the work I think it entails - we do not need to make this about cost.  I just want to know if I am right about adding 2 elbows to each side.

Comment: It's not clear what is being asked here, it may help to add some images or a better description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a plumber friend come to take a look at it.  He notched out the joist an inch and pushed it up.

Comment: Did he have a gas leakage detector on him?

Comment: Yes. He hit about 6 different hand-off with the wand.  This literally took him 15 mins total to do.